# Debug without step into any code in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Is there any tool or techniques that can capture all the variable values and output it to a text file. I'm trying to avoid using break point and stepping into the code in Visual studio for debugging and want to rely more on getting some sort of debug data dump.

Comment: I have to ask ... why?

Comment: Have you considered putting some logging into your code?

Comment: If you need to know the value of all variables, you're probably doing something wrong. Debugging is not about gathering as much data as possible. It's about zooming in on the small, relevant parts.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, some of the best advice I've heard all day!

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, yes you're correct. I do debug on the questionable section of the code but because I want to avoid relying too much on Visual Studio. I though if I can capture everything then I can look for the specific. Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a utility, [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900).  Of course, you'll need to ensure you call it at the appropriate time, and that you have symbols and so forth to debug the resulting minidump.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do it via code, no external tools needed. You can have [a trace listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t.aspx) that writes to a file, for example. In the link there is even an example on how to do it. You could write to a console instead, and see things happening as your program is run.

You could also [log info in the system events](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024/en-us). This is useful when you want to record information about app-crashing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ultimate only, but you might want to look into IntelliTrace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336126.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to debug some real time running I suggest the `Debug.Write`

```
Debug.Write("Some data:" + cData.ToString());
```

and read the output using the [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from Sysinternals.

I totally agree with "Brian Rasmussen" comments, but sometimes, some small data and actions you need to monitor them in real time.